# How to put vlines in all xltabular except the outer borderlines in xltabular table?

Tags: tables, border, xltabular

I have a very long table and I use the xltabular to do so.
the  code '\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{*{5}{L}}`is already without the`|` so it should be   without the horizontal line outside the table:
the packages used were:

```
\newcommand{\VerbL}{0.52\textwidth}
\newcommand{\LatL}{0.42\textwidth}
\usepackage[margin=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{array, makecell, multirow, xltabular}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}
```

The code is the following:

```
\begingroup
\footnotesize
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\setcellgapes{3pt}
\makegapedcells
\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{*{5}{L}}
    \caption{Long table caption.}
    \label{long} \\   
    \Xhline{1pt}
\multicolumn{5}{|c|}{Begin of Table}\\
    \hline
\textbf{Chave} & \textbf{Nome}   & \textbf{Tarefa/Banda} & \textbf{Análise} & \textbf{Contexto}\\
    \Xhline{0.5pt}
\endfirsthead
    \caption[]{Continuation} \\
    \Xhline{1pt}
\textbf{Chave} & \textbf{Nome}   & \textbf{Tarefa/Banda} & \textbf{Análise} & \textbf{Contexto}\\
    \hline
\endhead
    \Xhline{1pt}
\endfoot
     \hline
     \multicolumn{5}{|c|}{End of Table}\\
     \Xhline{1pt}
\endlastfoot
%%%% table body
\lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] \\ \hline
\lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] \\ \hline
\lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] \\ \hline
\lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] \\ \hline
\lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] \\ \hline
\lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] \\ \hline
\lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] \\ \hline
\lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] \\ \hline
\lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] \\ \hline
\lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66] \\ \hline
\end{xltabular}
\endgroup
```

which gives:

[image]
I would like to be:
[image]

I've already tried to put the `\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{*{5}{|L|}}` or the `\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{|*{5}{L|}}` or even `{\linewidth}{*{|5|}{L}}`  and it didnt worked.

Could someone  help-me?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Do you have  black background as in the image?

Comment: No, it's an acessibility tool in okular, it just inverts the colors of any pdf.

Comment: It works, thanks a lot ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{L|L|L|L|L}` instead of `\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{*{5}{L}}`

[image: a]